# What is wrong with my list naming code?

Tags: bash, filenames, long-filenames, short-filenames

I would like to change the file name from `Sub****_Ses1`  to `HU_TT_12_****_UU;`
(**** numbered from 0001 to 1600)

I did the below

```
#!/bin/sh
#Change file name 

Subj_id=/Users/dave/biomark/dat

cd Subj_id

for abcd in Sub****_Ses1; do

mv Sub$a$b$c$d_Ses1 HU_TT_12_$a$b$c$d_UU;

done
```

Comment: Hello HelpMe! Welcome to SO! You have asked a valid question. Seeing your comments on answers, Up-votes are for useful and good answers. They are not to be used to show gratitude (unless the answer is good).  Read the help article on [When to use upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up).

Comment: Thank you. The answer was helpful and wanted to up vote. Ill wait till i have enough reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for` and wildcards don't work like this. Use [`cut`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut) to extract the number.

```
$ touch Sub000{1,2,3,4}_Ses1 
$ for f in Sub????_Ses1      
do
    abcd=$(echo $f | cut -b4-7)
    mv $f HU_TT_12_${abcd}_UU
done
$ ls HU_TT_12_000*
HU_TT_12_0001_UU  HU_TT_12_0002_UU  HU_TT_12_0003_UU  HU_TT_12_0004_UU
```

Comment: I have 1600 files. should i do HU_TT_12_0001_UU  HU_TT_12_0002_UU  HU_TT_12_0003_UU  HU_TT_12_0004_UU till HU_TT_12_1600_UU??! or will this work on all of them? Also what did you only * the last digit ($ ls HU_TT_12_000*)?

Comment: I don't understand. The wildcard `Sub????_Ses1` will match *all* thes files. You don't have to name them.

Comment: Im wondering why did you add this? HU_TT_12_0001_UU HU_TT_12_0002_UU HU_TT_12_0003_UU HU_TT_12_0004_UU till HU_TT_12_1600_UU?

Comment: I don't. The first bash command of my example (`touch ...`) is just the create four files I want to move. The third bash command (`ls HU_TT_12_000*`) is to verify everything work. The answer to your question is the *second* bash command starting at `fro f in ...` and ending at `done`. Just try these on your files.

Comment: Sorry i can't up vote you because, I'm a noob! (I need 15 whatevs to do that!)

Answer (score 1):

You can use sed and mv

```
       #!/bin/bash
       set -x
       Subj_id=/Users/dave/biomark/dat
       cd $Subj_id

       for i in Sub*_Ses1 ; do
       #echo $i|sed -r 's/^.*\([[:digit:]]{4}\).*/HU_TT_12_\1_UU/'
       mv $i $(echo $i|sed -rn 's/^.*([[:digit:]]{4}).*/HU_TT_12_\1_UU/ p')
       done
```

Comment: I feel bad for not being to up vote people that are helping me..Sorry!

Comment: No problem... You can upvote, when you have enough reputation